# How do you make the Shader Editor Node Interface bigger?

Tags: interface, shader-nodes

Currently my Shader Editor is too small and hard to read. Anyone know how I can make it larger? All the other tool bars in other viewports are a good size and easy to see.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked out the view options?

- Middle Mouse scroll in the editor to adjust size
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to maximize the editor
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to take the editor to full screen mode

With the last two, the same keys will toggle you back to the original view.